# Azure App Service recently started throwing an error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.4.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I didn't change anything, and my Azure App Service started throwing the error:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>
> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.4.0 ...

Which seemed odd, so I tried adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v2.1.4 with Nuget, and from that i just get a white error screen with

> This page isn’t working
>
> [WEBSITE] is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

With no other errors.

This all works perfectly fine locally (as always...) - I am not sure where to go from here? Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: What are the details in your log about the 500 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of the different versions between packages.
Please use this command in PM.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 2.0.3
```

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9251).